# CSS: Text wont center?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, alignment

Can anybody see where I am going wrong with this? I am trying to center the text in a button for the navigation using CSS.

```
#nav {
margin:20px 0 0 0;

}

#nav ul {
margin:0;
}

#nav li:first-child {
width:80px;
height:30px;
display:inline-block;
background-color:#8f00ae;
text-align:center;
 }   
#nav ul li a {  
}
```

And here is my html.

```
    <!-- Navigation Section -->
        <div class="cl" id="nav">
            <div class="menu-top_nav-container">
<ul id="menu-top_nav" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-13">
<a href="http://localhost:8888/?cat=3">Features</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category   menu-item-18">
<a href="http://localhost:8888/?cat=4">Noize Live</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably because the navigation is being floated.. therefor it does not respond to text-align:center; Its difficult without access to the whole html and css sheets but try the following:

```
#nav li:first-child a 
{
padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Comment: Float didn't effect text-align:center;

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem. Further down the stylesheet it was floated.

Comment: It's set to inline-block and has a defined width. Float will not force the element to collapse. If adding left and right padding to it 'fixed' the centering, it's because the width wasn't wide enough to give the perception of centered text.

Comment: I didn't add any padding Removing the float did fix the problem.